# Check if all fields of a type are "primitives"

Tags: c++

For some reason I would like to do something like:

```
template<typename Data>
void write(const Data& data) {
    std::fstream out {...};
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&data), sizeof(Data));
    out.flush();
}
```

`Data` is a type that has only primitive types, or to be more specific types that are trivially copyable. Does it mean that if I use `static_assert (std::is_trivially_copyable<Data>::value, "");` inside `write()` I am really sure no type can be passed to the function which can not be reinterpreted as bytes? Or is there any other condition I should check in static_assert?

Comment: maybe `std::is_convertible` could help?

Comment: @Moia std::is_convertible takes two types, From and To and this is not what I want to check.

Comment: aren't those `Data` and `const char*` ?

Comment: @Moia We do not care about implicit/user-defined conversions, this is reinterpretation as bytes.

Comment: It interesting, but I think it does not work, since I have checked for struct X { int n; }; static_assert (std::is_convertible<Data, const char*>::value, ""); static assertion failed.

Comment: Is should be pointed out that this solution will write out possible padding between `Data` members as well, which may not be what you wanted.

Comment: @geza thanks for pointing it out. I think that in this kind of situation I have it will not be a problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? In C++, all objects can be examined as bytes, so the answer to your question is that even `is_trivially_copyable` is unnecessary.

Comment: Notice also that you may have endianness issue.

Comment: @geza I mean, struct X { std::string p; }; converted to bytes (by reinterpret) and then creating X from these bytes gives you in my option segfault. I want to be sure, that what I pass to write function can be safely converted to and from bytes, that's it.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's right

Comment: @ArturPyszczuk: this information is missing from your question. In that case, `is_trivially_copyable` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I guess **trivially-copyable**ness doesn't realy tell something about safty.

But anyway, you should decide by yourself.

#### For example:

Assuming Data contain a pointer of a **non-trivially-copyable** type. the pointer itself is actually **trivially-copyable**, and it make the whole type **trivially-copyable**. But is there any sence to write a pointer value to a file?

So even if you decide to check each member value if it is **trivially-copyable**, and get positive answer, it doesn't necessarily means that you can write this type to a file.

#### Another example:

In the other hand, if a type consist of only primitive types and have a copy or move constructor, it is calssified as **non-trivially-copyable**, but it is totaly safe to be written into a file.

Comment: Sure, you are right. With a pointer can be a dangerous situation. Non-trivially-copyable types also can be banned even if those can be reinterpreted as bytes, but I think, for now it is less important for me.

Comment: I think the easy solution to such as problem is to implement serialize/deserialize logic in manner to write/read from a file. this way you can implement the logic for any type. this way, any type without the implementation won't be compiled.

Comment: That is cool, but sometimes types that you want to use are not "yours" so you need to wrap them, anyway it can be done.